# How can I check the file names through python a script in python?

Tags: python, django, csv, file

I am using python scripts to save web scraped data to CSV files. The name of CSV files is dynamic, like fl_todays_date.csv where today's date is the date derived from the web scraped site. After saving the data in a CSV file, I then import the CSV data into my Django models, all through the script. But the problem I'm facing is, How can I check whether the data from yesterday's file is already present in the database before importing today's data.

My file structure is as follows:

```
csv_files
    fl_some_pervious.csv
    fl_yesterday.csv
    fl_today.csv
```

```
script
    scrape.py
    db_upload.py
```

I tried something like this:

```py
def run():
    file = open('./src/csv_files/floor_sheet_data.csv')
    read_file = csv.reader(file)
    
    count = 1

    for record in read_file:
        if count==1:
            pass
        else:
            try:
                obj = MyModel.objects.get(org_symbol=record[4], contract_no=record[5])
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                
                org = AnotherModel.objects.get(symbol=record[4])
                MyModel.objects.create(org=org, s_n=record[1],contract_no=record[2],date=record[3],buyer_broker=record[5],seller_broker=record[6],quantity=record[7],rate=record[8],amount=record[9])
        count += 1
```

I'm passing the files manually here. How can I make it automatic?

Comment: [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) can be used to list all the files in a specified directory. You can then filter them by extension

Comment: @loonatick I can list the files but I want to access the file names and check if the dates in the file name are already present in the database or not.

Comment: So, something like [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)?